# Perl/SQLite - How do I select / update a row with the prepare method?

Tags: perl, sqlite

I have the following code

```
my $db = DBI->connect(
     "dbi:SQLite:data.db", "", "",
     { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1, PrintError => 0 }
);
my $row = $db->selectall_arrayref(
     "SELECT * FROM something WHERE name=\'$hash->{name}\'");
print Dumper $row;
```

How do I do the same with `my $sql = $db->prepare("......");  $sql->execute($hash->{name});` so that it's escaped correctly and I have the selected data in `$row`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for information on [bind values](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values):

```
my $row = $db->selectall_arrayref(
    "SELECT * FROM something WHERE name=?",
    {},
    $hash->{name}
);
```

This prepares and executes in one go.

You can also prepare and execute separately:

```
my $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM something WHERE name=?");
```

later:

```
$sth->execute($hash->{name});
my $rows_ref = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
```

You should avoid using `SELECT *` and read the section on [Statement Handle Methods in perldoc DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#Statement_Handle_Methods).